# python imaplib reading gmail

Tags: python

I am using imaplib to read gmail messages in my python command window.  The only problem is if that the emails come with with newlines and return carriages.  Also, the text does not seem to be formatted correct.  Instead of Amount: $36.49, it returns =2436.49. How can I go about cleaning up this text? Thanks!

Sample email content:

```
r\nItem name: Scanner\r\nItem=23: 130585100869\r\nPurchase Date: Oct 7, 2011\r\nUnit Price: =2436.49 USD\r\nQty: 1\r\nAmount: =2436.49USD\r\nSubtotal: =2436.49 USD\r\nShipping and handling: =240.00 USD\r\nInsurance - not offered
```

Code:

```
import imaplib
import libgmail
import re
import email
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

USER = 'email@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'password'

#connecting to the gmail imap server
imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
imap_server.login(USER, PASSWORD)
imap_server.select('Inbox')

typ, response = imap_server.search(None, '(SUBJECT "payment received")')

Data = []

for i in response[0].split():
    results, data = imap_server.fetch(i, "(RFC822)")
    Data.append(data)
    break

for i in Data:
    print i
```

Comment: This is not HTML, so Beautiful Soup will not help you here.  Does it help to know that `\r\n` is a line terminator, and (if this is the encoding it appears to be) all occurrences of `=XX` need to be replaced with the ASCII character with hexadecimal codepoint XX?

Comment: Are those actual `\r\n` characters or carriage-return-linefeeds?

Comment: Oh, you asked for modules: [`quopri`](http://docs.python.org/library/quopri.html) will decode the `=XX` notation for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The `\r\n` issue

The `\r\n` problem is caused by you not printing strings, but internal representations thereof. Try this to understand what I mean:

```
print ['test\n']
print 'test\n'
```

The `i` that you print above is a list of strings, so first representation kicks in. Try this:

```
print(Data[0][0][1])
```

I identified this by inspection of the object -- you should read the documentation of the libraries you are using to understand what exactly this object is composed of to understand why specifically this field represents the message. Or how to convert the `Data` object to something more... palatable.

### The encoding issue

Try:

```
import quopri
print quopri.decodestring(Data[0][0][1])
```

Comment: Advice: when you copy-paste code, make sure to select it and press the double brace button to indent it by 4 spaces. Also check the *preview* of your text below the input box, before you submit, to make sure it looks alright. It is generally a "turn-off" for others when they see badly formatted questions -- it's in your interest to make them look attractive. Now to the actual problem at hand...

Answer (score 6):

The data is in quoted-printable encoding, this is a little data massager that should get you what you want:

```
text = '''\r\nPurchase Date: Oct 7, 2011\r\nUnit Price: =2436.49 USD\r\nQty: 1\r\nAmount: =2436.49 USD\r\nSubtotal: =2436.49 USD\r\nShipping and handling: =240.00 USD\r\nInsurance - not offered : ----\r\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\r\nTax: --\r\nTotal: =2436.49 USD\r\nPayment: =2436.49 USD\r\nPayment sent to: emailaddress=40gmail.com\r\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n\r\nSincerely,\r\nPayPal\r\n=20\r\n----------------------------------------------------------------------\r\nHelp Center:=20\r\nhttps://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/helpweb?cmd=3D_help\r\nSecurity Center:=20\r\nhttps://www.paypal.com/us/security\r\n\r\nThis email was sent by an automated system, so if you reply, nobody will =\r\nsee it. To get in touch with us, log in to your account and click =\r\n=22Contact Us=22 at the bottom of any page.\r\n\r\n'''

raw_data = text.decode("quopri") #replace =XX for the real characters

data = [map(str.strip, l.split(":")) for l in raw_data.splitlines() if ": " in l]

print data
# [['Purchase Date', 'Oct 7, 2011'], ['Unit Price', '$36.49 USD'], ['Qty', '1'], ['Amount', '$36.49 USD'], ['Subtotal', '$36.49 USD'], ['Shipping and handling', '$0.00 USD'], ['Insurance - not offered', '----'], ['Tax', '--'], ['Total', '$36.49 USD'], ['Payment', '$36.49 USD'], ['Payment sent to', 'emailaddress@gmail.com'], ['Help Center', ''], ['Security Center', '']]
```

There you have your data in a much easier to process format, I hope it helps.

Edit: to make it even cuter:

```
>>> cooked = dict(data)
>>> print cooked["Unit Price"]
$36.49 USD
```

Answer (score 1):

If these are actually email messages, you can use the [`email` module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html) to get you started. You can use it to do the proper quoted-printable decoding and get some clean text.

After that, though, you will need to write your own code to extract the parts you want. This is not a standard format for which parsers would exist. I would use regular expressions.

Note that `\r\n` is *most likely* just the carriage-return character followed by a linefeed character, not "slash, r, slash, n". In an interactive terminal Python will represent control and whitespace characters with their symbolic form.

Answer (score 0):

Just use split and then check to see if the line matches what you're looking for.

You can pretty it up a bit, but this is a fairly simply way to handle it.

```
f = yourBlockOfText

text = f.split('\\r\\n')
for line in text:
    if line[0:4] == "Unit":
         print line
    elif line[0:17] == "Payment sent to: ":
        print line
```